# If gravitation causes constant acceleration why moon does not fall into earth?

Tags: gravity, acceleration, velocity

If moon travels with constant speed in one direction and earth gravitation causes constant acceleration in perpendicular direction why moon does not eventually fall into earth? I mean if gravitation causes moon to fall faster each second (10m/s2) shouldn't after time velocity toward earth be big enough to cause it to fall ?

Comment: Certainly this is a duplicate of some other question!

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9049/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The value of g (10m/s2) doesn't apply to the moon, since that is Earth's surface gravity. It's about 1000 times smaller when you are as far away as the moon.

Comment: [XKCD's related explanation](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/): "To avoid falling...into the atmosphere, you have to go sideways really, really fast."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be said that the *tangential speed* of the moon in its orbit is represented by a vector that is constant in magnitude, **but not so his direction**. This variation of the vector direction (always remains tangent to lunar orbit), is actually a change in velocity, and therefore *acceleration*.

[image]

Why the moon does not fall on the ground? Simplifying to a circular orbit, the [centripetal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) acting on the moon's is the gravitational force, while by the movement itself, a [centrifugal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) that keeps the system in balance, is generated.

Comment: You could also explain that the gravitational force isn't so much pulling the moon to the earth as stopping the moon from flinging itself off into space.

Comment: @PipperChip Yes! It's a very good point of view! Tanks for your comment... !

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration can change velocity in two ways - by changing its magnitude, and by changing its direction.

Essentially, Earth's gravity is constantly steering the moon around the Earth.

Your initial premise - "If moon travels with constant speed in one direction" - is incorrect.  The moon's direction is constantly being changed by the gravitational acceleration.