# Why does a velocity that gives gravity's centripetal acceleration make you stay in orbit?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Explanations of basic orbital mechanics that I can find all go,

$$\frac{v_{satellite}^2}{r} = a_c = \frac{F_{gravity}}{M_{planet}} = \frac{(\frac{G M_a M_s}{r^2})}{M_{planet}}$$

, and so you get a velocity,

$$v_{satellite}=\sqrt{\frac{GM_{planet}}{r}}$$

. So you need that velocity to orbit earth at that radius. But it doesn't answer alot of questions like:

**How much can you increase or decrease your velocity for this *v* and *r* relationship to stop?**

**What changes when you reach those points which makes you fly away or crash into the earth?**

**Why would increasing *v* of the satellite effect something perpendicular like the *a*c?**

**Why does having a centripetal acceleration equal the force from gravity, 9.81, prevent you from crashing?**

Comment: Because you keep falling at the planet (or other primary) and *missing*. Cue Douglas Adams  quote.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9049/.

Comment: Ok, but what about the 3rd and 4th question? And what does a rocket that is trying to get out of orbit do? And will something orbit at 1m above the surface of the earth if it is going fast enough?

Comment: Yes it would orbit 1m above the Earth if it went fast enough, if there was no atmosphere and the Earth was absolutely smooth and spherical.

Comment: A lot of questions.  Perhaps too many.  It suggests to me that you really need tuition rather than a single answer to a specific question.  You cite the equations but you don't seem to understand them.  I think you need to study  a textbook or an online tutorial video.

Comment: Centripetal acceleration results from the force of gravity being unbalanced.  Meaning, the force of gravity is the source of the centripetal acceleration for curved motion in a gravitational field in the absence of other forces.  Centripetal acceleration is not a thing by itself that can "balance" other things, it is a consequence of unbalanced forces in curved motion.