# Would moon fall if Earth was not rotating?

Tags: forces

Would moon fall to Earth if Earth wasnt rotating ? And if rotating at what height moon would have to be to ignor orbiting and fall ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why doesn't the Moon fall upon Earth?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9049/50583)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

No, the moon stays in orbit due to its translational motion relative to the center of the earth.  The Earth's rotatation is not a factor in keeping the moon in orbit.

Think of it this way -- the moon is moving across the sky, while falling.  By the time it's fallen a little bit, it's moved out of the way of the earth a little bit, too.  These effects exactly cancel out, and this keeps the moon moving in a circle.  (well, actually an ellipse, but close enough for the purposes of this)