# Why does the Earth not fall towards the Sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, solar-system

According to http://wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/mobile/2013/07/01/why-doesnt-the-earth-fall-down/ , the earth does not fall down because of the gravitational force of the sun.

At the same time , earth's repulsive force , acts as a resistance to the gravitational force of the sun.

This theory is not satisfying because it doesn't hold good for mercury.

Mercury's mass is negligible when compared to sun.  So sun should have swallowed mercury already.

Is there a better theory to why the earth doesn't fall.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9049/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The earth DOES fall towards the sun, but it moves sideways as it's doing so.  The sideways movement ensures that the orbit is approximately circular.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cannonball

Comment: The link you provided contradicts your question and provides the answer you are looking for. Nothing about it says the earth isn't falling towards the sun