# Why do moons not get pulled into the planet while they clear their neighborhood?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, planets, solar-system, moon

Today, my 6 year old and I were discussing dwarf planets and their characteristics. We were talking about how, to be a considered a planet, the planet needs to clear it's neighborhood (as explained in an video he and I watched).

This is just the background. My son wanted to type the actual question... here it is:

> Why do moons not get pulled into the planet while they clear their neighborhood?

Thank you for taking the time to answer my son's curiosity and sorry that this post format (probably) doesn't adhere to posting guidelines... He REALLY wanted to type out the question though.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't the Moon fall onto the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9049/2451)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the Moon fall onto the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9049/)